# How to select all items in a list using jQuery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am creating a dynamic list on these lines:

```
<li class="MainMenuList" data-role=list-divider>
    <li data-icon=check id="1">
        <a name="n1" id="id-1">Text-1</a>
    </li>
    <li data-icon=check id="2">
        <a name="n2" id="id-2">Text-1</a>
    </li>
    <li data-icon=check id="3">
        <a name="n3" id="id-3">Text-1</a>
    </li>
</li>
```

How can I run JQuery .each() selector to access all the value in the list. Trying this doesn't produce ant result.

```
$( ".MainMenuList li a" ).each(function( index ) {
    var n1 = $(this).attr('name');
    var n2 = parseInt ($(this).attr('id'));
    alert( index + "-" + n1 + "-" + n2);
});
```

Comment: Your HTML in invalid.

Comment: To expand on that rather concise comment, your li tags should be contained within either a ul (unordered list) or an ol (ordered list) tag

Comment: Your parseInt will throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQYyY/) of your code

- As mentioned in the comments, your first `<li>` element should be a `<ul>`
- You should also either change the `<a>` `id` to strictly a number (since your parsing it as an integer) or just retrieve the number part (via `substr` or something else)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that worked. I think the main mistake I was making was non-use of <ul>, although the list was still working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks All others for their input also. Yes it was a crude HTML (extracted from main code). But I found the mistake that I was not using ul hence unable to use the selector properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is invalid, the outside li should be a ul for it to be valid.

```
<ul class="MainMenuList" data-role=list-divider>
    <li data-icon=check id="1">
        <a name="n1" id="id-1">Text-1</a>
    </li>
    <li data-icon=check id="2">
        <a name="n2" id="id-2">Text-1</a>
    </li>
    <li data-icon=check id="3">
        <a name="n3" id="id-3">Text-1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This line

```
var n2 = parseInt ($(this).attr('id'));
```

is the same as

```
var n2 = parseInt("id-2");
```

and parseInt will not return the 2, it will return NaN.

You would have to use a regular expression

```
$(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0]
```

or split to pull out the number

```
$(this).attr('id').split("-")[1]
```

or you could just reference the parents id if that is a valid assumption.

```
$(this).parent().attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `parseInt()` on a string. If you know your IDs will always be in the form `id-N` you could just do

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var n2 = parseInt(id.split("-")[1]);
```